# Google Subscription Price Increase for new users only

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, subscription

I want to increase the existing subscription for my app, for iOS I am given the ability to "maintain current price for existing subscribers" is that a feature that google has as well?

My plan is to increase the price and allow 3 months for my existing users to use the app at their current price, and then finally increase it for them after the 3 months time span. Is this possible with the google play store subscriptions? Or am I going to have to only offer a new subscription to new users and update the price after 3 months for my existing users?